# Prolog: why is true == not(not(true)) -> false?

Tags: prolog, logical-operators

Obviously `true = not(not(true))` has to be false, because `=` tries to unify the atom `true` with the term `not(not(true))` (without evaluating the term), which is false, since the terms are not identical.

However, I thought `==` really compares whatever is evaluated. Thus, I thought `true == not(not(true))` should evaluate to `true == true`, just like (for arithmetic operators) `4 =:= 2 + 2` would evaluate to `4 =:= 4` and return true.

...but this is what I get in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- true == not(not(true)).
false.
```

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: You used `not(not(false))` in one place and `not(not(true))` in others. Was that deliberate?

Comment: No, a typo. Sry. Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(==)/2` does not *compare whatever is evaluated*. It does not evaluate its arguments. It only succeeds if the arguments are already instantiated to matching terms.

In prolog, `not(not(true))` is a compound term, which is the term `not/1` with a single argument, `not(true)`, itself being a term `not/1` of one argument consisting of the term `true/0` which has no arguments. It doesn't have a value. It doesn't even get "executed" except in certain contexts. In Prolog, the predicate `not/1` succeeds if it's argument fails, and it fails if its argument succeeds. This isn't the *value* or *functional result*, but a behavior. This is assuming that it appears in a context such as the following:

```
not(not(true)),
write('This will be written out because not(not(true)) succeeded'), nl.
```

The expression `true == not(not(true))` in Prolog is a compound term, equivalent to:

```
'=='(true, not(not(true)))
```

In this context, `not(not(true))` is not evaluated. Prolog will first exercise the `(==)/2` equivalence operator, which succeeds if its arguments are instantiated to the same term. Are the terms `true` and `not(not(true))` in Prolog the same (or equivalent)? No they are not. One is simple term with no arguments (`true/0`). The other is a compound term: a term with one argument that is itself a term with one argument. Thus the `(==)/2` fails here.

Note that `(=:=)/2` is quite different. It is an operator that compares results of arithmetic expressions. The arguments must be evaluable arithmetic expressions and `(=:=)/2` will succeed if they evaluate to the same result, and it will fail if they do not.

Comment: Rather `(==)/2`

Comment: @false indeed, I was being a bit lazy.

Comment: Still lazy, I mean the round brackets around, otherwise it's one token `==/`